# Python string generator, in a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program, that when run will make a random string from a list of characters that i have defined.
The code is:

```
from random import randint
from random import *
import random
Upperletters=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
Lowerletters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
Symbols = ["!","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","-","+","="]
Numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
random.shuffle(Symbols)
random.shuffle(Numbers)
random.shuffle(Upperletters)
random.shuffle(Lowerletters)
randomlength = randint(8, 12)
stringgenerator = ''.join(choice(Upperletters + Symbols + Numbers + 
Lowerletters) for x in range(randomlength))
print(stringgenerator)
stringgeneratorlower = stringgenerator.lower()
letter_combos = ["qwe","wer","ert","rty","tyu","yui","uio","iop","asd","sdf","dfg","fgh","ghj","hjk","jkl","zxc","xcv","cvb","vbn","bnm"]
keyboard =int(sum(stringgeneratorlower.count(fragment) for fragment in letter_combos))
if keyboard >= 1:
    print("Bad try again")
```

But my problem is that i would like the string to use the symbols in the order they're added in, so it should be uppercase characters first, then some symbols then some numbers and then the lowercase. My problem is, it generates them in a completely random order. How can i make it generate them in the order i would like, so that the string generated doesn't contain any of the letter_combos from the list?

Comment: Do you want it to use the Upperletters, Lowerletters, Symbols and Numbers in the order that they are in the array OR do you want it to use Upperletters first, then use Lowerletters, then use Symbols and finally use Numbers?

Comment: Your imports are redundant/ inconsistent. Why not make up your mind?

Comment: Can you give examples for current outputs and desired outputs?

Comment: @kyle yes that would be ideal

Comment: Is the part after `print(stringgenerator)` really necessary for your question?

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann yeah, its the checking part, so it doesn't copy consecutive letters on a keybaord, otherwise i would be done.

Comment: @johnnu Hmm, ok. Though looks like you already got that part and are just lacking the "from upper to lower" thing.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I've over complicated this a little, but the actual thing im trying to do is make a string from 8-12 characters in length with my character lists, and then check it so its not in the letter_combos list

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDIT FIXED IT**
I only started coding a year ago and have never used sorted so I didn't bother with it. I changed up your code a bit. I removed Shuffle because why should you randomly pick something from a shuffled list? that's the same as randomly picking from a sorted one!
[Full code](https://pastebin.com/yju3hChE)

```
def shuffle():
    randomlength = randint(8, 12)
    pre = {0: '', 1:'',2:'',3:''}
    lists = {0: Upperletters, 1: Lowerletters, 2: Symbols, 3: Numbers}
    for x in range(4): pre[x]+=(choice(lists[x]))
    for i in range(randomlength-4):
        x = randint(1, 74)
        if x < 27: pre[0]+=choice(lists[0])
        elif x < 53: pre[1]+=choice(lists[1])
        elif x < 65: pre[2]+=choice(lists[2])
        else: pre[3]+=choice(lists[3])
    pw = ''
    for v in pre.values():
           pw += v
    return pw
print(shuffle())
```

Comment: You changed the probability distribution, though. For example you made digits much more likely than they were.

Comment: @StefanPochmann uh no I didn't it's a 25 percent chance for each of the 4 types

Comment: Yes. Exactly. 25% for each. Which it wasn't originally.

Comment: @StefanPochmann well true I didn't know it had to be the same probability

Comment: @Eli Lopez, that also does a good job, but it doesn't always give me a definite Uppercase, lowercase, Number and Symbol.

Comment: @EliLopez it does, it says "uppercase characters first, then some symbols then some numbers and then the lowercase."

Comment: @johnnu no where does it say definite

Comment: @EliLopez in the paragraph after my code, it says i would like the string to go in the order they're added in, so uppercase first then symbols then lowercase, then numbers.

Comment: @johnnu ok sorry I interpreted that it was random amount of each with no minimum amount. I updated the code to your liking

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to assign a weight to each category, and then sort the generated string by those weights:

```
import string
from random import choice, randint

symbols = '!$%^&*()_-+='

categories = [
    string.ascii_uppercase,
    symbols,
    string.digits,
    string.ascii_lowercase,
]
choices = ''.join(categories)
weights = {char: n for n, chars in enumerate(categories) for char in chars}

length = randint(8, 12)
rand_unordered = [choice(choices) for _ in range(length)]
rand_ordered = ''.join(sorted(rand_unordered, key=weights.get))
```

Comment: I find the name "choices" slightly confusing, would call it "options" instead.

Comment: Nice solution! I'd rename "weights" to something like "category_index".

Comment: Ok guys I will figure out some better names right after I've solved cache invalidation